# Command line to check with pdf page contains images

Tags: pdfbox, pypdf, pdfminer, poppler, pdf-to-html

I currectly use `pdftohtml` from `poppler` to generate html output from a pdf file, then check which page contains image in the html file.

Is there a command line program that can directly print the numbers of the pages that contain images?

Comment: Not in PDFBox as command line tool. Could be done in java.

Comment: Any simple program in python is also fine. Pdftohtml still write the image as png files. I’d like to to avoid generating those files.

Comment: PDFBox is for Java, or for JVMs. (Some people use kotlin)

Comment: You can use https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-images.html